# How to insert a formula into a function so that it can be used to calculate values for consecutive rows

Tags: r, function, dplyr, formula

I'm aware that the title may be a little confusing but please allow me to clarify.
I have a column with values

```
> df
    Direction
    139
    118
    180
    142
    185
    224
    137
    245
```

I have the following formula

```
((pt1 - pt2 + 180)%%360 - 180)
```

I would like to insert this formula to calculate the difference between each consecutive instance
Example:

```
((139 - 118 + 180)%%360 - 180) = 21
((118 - 180 + 180)%%360 - 180) = -62
```

Some of the things I've tried

Creating the function

```
angle <- function(turn1, turn2) {
  coursediff <- ((turn1 - turn2 + 180)
                 %%360 - 180)
  coursediff
}
angle(118, 180)
## [1] -62
```

Trying to use it for each consecutive row for column Direction, creating a new column named Diff

```
df$Diff <- with(df, 
     ave(Direction, ID,  FUN=function(angle) c(NA, diff(angle))))
```

Or

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(gap=angle(c(NA,diff(Direction)), 1))
```

Or

```
index <- function(angle) c(0, diff(angle))
DT <- data.table(df)
DT[, Diff := index(Direction), by = "ID"]
```

Or even

```
transform(df, 
          Diff=unlist(tapply(Direction, ID, 
                                function(angle) c(0, diff(Direction)))))
```

All the above attempts are giving me the same answers as if I were to simply take the difference per row, like so

```
df$Diff <- c(NA, diff(df$Direction))
```

This is what I get now

```
> df
    Direction  Diff  ID
    139        NA    1
    118       -21    1
    180        62    1
    142       -38    1
    185        NA    2
    224        39    2
    137       -87    2
    245        108   2
```

I hope someone can help me out, much appreciated!

Comment: You are right.  I lost that.  Removing comment.

Comment: Hi @akrun I'm not sure what a rolling difference is. I just need the function/formula to work for each consecutive row and index it by ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ave` and `diff` in base R like this.

```
dat$diff <- ave(dat$Direction, dat$ID,
                FUN=function(x) c(NA, (rev((diff(rev(x))) + 180) %% 360) -180))
```

Here, we calculate in the desired order by feeding `diff` the reversed vector using `rev` and return the vector in the desired order using `rev` on the output of `diff`. Note that we need to use `c(NA, ..)` to add a missing value for each ID.

which returns

```
dat
  Direction Diff ID diff
1       139   NA  1   NA
2       118  -21  1   21
3       180   62  1  -62
4       142  -38  1   38
5       185   NA  2   NA
6       224   39  2  -39
7       137  -87  2   87
8       245  108  2 -108
```

**data**

```
dat <-
structure(list(Direction = c(139L, 118L, 180L, 142L, 185L, 224L, 
137L, 245L), Diff = c(NA, -21L, 62L, -38L, NA, 39L, -87L, 108L
), ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("Direction", 
"Diff", "ID"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi @Imo thank you for your answer, doesn't quite work yet though, for instance, the formula is supposed to return 21 and -62 for the first two values. Function x is supposed to subtract turn2 from turn1. Now the values are still the same..

Comment: Ah. I missed that. Added a couple of `rev`s to get the desired output.

Comment: Thanks again @Imo

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
angle(118, 180)
## [1] -62
```

Means

```
angle(line1, line2)
```

You are comparing a direction with its consecutive, e.g. the next one.

In the other functions you wrote, the order is reversed, that is

```
angle(line2, line1)
```

Just fix that and you obtain the result you want:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(diff = (Direction - lead(Direction) + 180) %% 360 -180)
#> Source: local data frame [8 x 4]
#> Groups: ID [2]
#> 
#>   Direction  Diff    ID  diff
#>       <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
#> 1       139    NA     1    21
#> 2       118   -21     1   -62
#> 3       180    62     1    38
#> 4       142   -38     1    NA
#> 5       185    NA     2   -39
#> 6       224    39     2    87
#> 7       137   -87     2  -108
#> 8       245   108     2    NA
```

Comment: Thanks @GGamba! I actually edited your code a little
df <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(diff=angle(c(NA,diff(Direction)), 0))
This seems to work!